# How can i use RoundedAvatarDrawable for creating round image?

Tags: android, layout, imageview, drawable

I'm using the class RoundedAvatarDrawable.java to draw a round image from a sample bitmap.
But for me it doesn't work or maybe i'm not using it to the right way.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/philm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/philm/in/drawable/RoundedAvatarDrawable.java

This my activity layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profil" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profil2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my activity code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.profil_activity_layout);
    getActionBar().setTitle("ROOT ACTIVITY");

    //Resources res = getResources();
    //Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.profil);

    Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.profil);
    RoundedAvatarDrawable RondedAvatarImg = new RoundedAvatarDrawable(bImage);

    Bitmap bImageRwonded = RondedAvatarImg.getBitmap();
    ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    mImg.setImageBitmap(bImageRwonded);

}
```

The ouput of the activity is

[image]

I was expecting to get a rounded photo in the second ImageView.
So could somebody explain to me what did i miss.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use below code as per ur need. we have write class for your CirculerImageView.

```
<com.widgets.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_image"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_img" />

public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

    /** The border width. */
    private int borderWidth;

    /** The canvas size. */
    private int canvasSize;

    /** The image. */
    private Bitmap image;

    /** The paint. */
    private Paint paint;

    /** The paint border. */
    private Paint paintBorder;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new circular image view.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            the context
     */
    public CircularImageView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new circular image view.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            the context
     * @param attrs
     *            the attrs
     */
    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.circularImageViewStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new circular image view.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            the context
     * @param attrs
     *            the attrs
     * @param defStyle
     *            the def style
     */
    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintBorder = new Paint();
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);

        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CircularImageView, defStyle, 0);
        if (attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border, true)) {
            setBorderWidth(attributes.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                    R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_width, 0));
            setBorderColor(attributes.getColor(
                    R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_color, Color.WHITE));
        }

    }

    /**
     * Sets the border width.
     * 
     * @param borderWidth
     *            the new border width
     */
    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.requestLayout();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the border color.
     * 
     * @param borderColor
     *            the new border color
     */
    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the shadow.
     */
    public void addShadow() {
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ImageView#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
     */
    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // load the bitmap
        image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
        // init shader
        if (image != null) {
            canvasSize = canvas.getWidth();
            if (canvas.getHeight() < canvasSize)
                canvasSize = canvas.getHeight();
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    image, canvasSize, canvasSize, false),
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);

            int circleCenter = (canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2;
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                    + borderWidth, ((canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2)
                    + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                    + borderWidth,
                    ((canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2) - 4.0f, paint);
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ImageView#onMeasure(int, int)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Measure width.
     * 
     * @param measureSpec
     *            the measure spec
     * @return the int
     */
    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            result = canvasSize;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Measure height.
     * 
     * @param measureSpecHeight
     *            the measure spec height
     * @return the int
     */
    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            result = canvasSize;
        }
        return (result + 2);
    }

    /**
     * Drawable to bitmap.
     * 
     * @param drawable
     *            the drawable
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

attrs.xml(add this in values folder)

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
        <attr name="border" format="boolean"></attr>
        <attr name="border_width" format="dimension"></attr>
        <attr name="border_color" format="color"></attr>
        <attr name="shadow" format="boolean"></attr>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="Theme">
        <attr name="circularImageViewStyle" format="reference"></attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your class i mange to import all those library :
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;

But the var are missing
R.styleable.CircularImageView
R.styleable.CircularImageView_borde
CircularImageView_border_width
CircularImageView_border_color

Comment: we need to add attrs.xml in values folder. i ll update code in above ans.check it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to found a solution :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.profil_activity_layout);
    getActionBar().setTitle("ROOT ACTIVITY");

    //Resources res = getResources();
    //Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.profil);

    BitmapDrawable bImage = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profil);
    RoundedAvatarDrawable RondedAvatarImg = new RoundedAvatarDrawable(bImage.getBitmap());

    Bitmap bImageRwonded = RondedAvatarImg.getBitmap();
    ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    mImg.setImageDrawable(new RoundedAvatarDrawable(bImage.getBitmap()));


}
```

And here is the output :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiqZf.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use following library to round your image. 
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

[Universal image loader roundedBitmapDisplayer issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603713/universal-image-loader-roundedbitmapdisplayer-issues)